# How can I retain datagridview information on a form and prevent a .Show() button from creating new instances?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview, html-agility-pack

I have two forms (Menu, Database) both with datagridviews. The first form has a button column that copies the row information to the datagridview on the other form and shows it. There is also a button on the first form that is meant to simply open up the instance of the previously opened 2nd form. I have 2 main issues that occur. The first is that the row copies over but when I press another column button on another row within the first form it opens up a new 2nd form rather than adding its value to the instance of the already opened form. The second issue is that once the X button on the top of the second form is pressed and the form closes the information is lost. I don't mind losing the information once the application is closed but, I want to retain it regardless of the second form closing. I have tried using singleton to keep the instance and Hide() during form closing events to prevent the second form from closing but, perhaps something is missing or wrong with my code.

First Form Menu

```
    //Open Database
    private void DB_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendRow = false;
        DataGridViewRow DB_GridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow();
        DataTable DB_Table = new DataTable();
        Database DB = new Database(DB_GridViewRow, SendRow);
        DB = Database.GetInstance();
        DB.Show();
    }

    //Copy To Database

    private void LeadsDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SendRow = true;
        DataTable DB_Table = new DataTable();
        DataGridView DB_GridView = new DataGridView();

        if (!_DB.Visible)
        {
            _DB = new Database(LeadsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex], SendRow);
            _DB.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            SendRow = false;
            _DB = Database.GetInstance();
            _DB.BringToFront();
        }
     }
```

Second Form Database

```
    DataTable DB_Table;
    BindingList<DataPile> DB_GridViewList = new BindingList<DataPile>();

    private static Database _instance = null;

    public static Database GetInstance()
    {
        bool SendRow = new bool();
        DataGridViewRow DB_GridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow();


        if (_instance == null) _instance = new Database(DB_GridViewRow, SendRow);
        return _instance;
    }

    public Database()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitDBTable();
        GetInstance();
        DB_GridView.DataSource = DB_GridViewList;
    }

    public Database(DataGridViewRow DB_GridViewRow, bool SendRow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitDBTable();
        DB_GridView.DataSource = DB_GridViewList;

        if (DB_GridViewList != null && SendRow == true)
        {
            DB_GridViewList.Add(new DataPile { BusinessName = (string)DB_GridViewRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue,
                                               PhoneNumber = (string)DB_GridViewRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue });
        }

     }

    public class DataPile
    {
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MonthlyRevenue { get; set; }
    }

    private void InitDBTable()
    {
        DB_Table = new DataTable("DB_GridTable");
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Business Name", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Phone Number", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Mobile Number", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Contact Name", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Monthly Revenue", typeof(string));
        DB_GridView.DataSource = DB_Table;
    }

    private void Database_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Database_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        e.Cancel = true; // this cancels the close event.
    }
}
```

Comment: Every second time you click the row it creates a new database. Get_Instance() sets the .Visible property to false which then creates a new Database() the next click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is confusing and using _instance isn't needed. This isn't my first choice of code, but here is a more straight forward approach to get you started.
You'll notice that the _instance is completely gone now as the main form always has direct access to your database through _DB. Also, you were creating DataTable, DataGridView & DataGridViewRows when it wasn't needed so those were removed. Lastly, I created a new row called UniqueID. Just make sure that this row creates a new ID each time. That way only one copy of your row will ever be transferred to the new Form.

You will have to handle transferring the changes back to your Main Form if that is what is required.

The Main Form:

```
    bool SendRow;
    Database _DB = new Database();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LeadsDataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "ABCD", "555-1234", "555-5555", "john doe", "jdoe@email.com", "1");
        LeadsDataGridView.Rows.Add("2", "EFGH", "555-9876", "555-1111", "jane white", "jwhite@email.com", "21");
    }

    //Copy To Database
    private void LeadsDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (e.ColumnIndex == LeadsDataGridView.Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.None, DataGridViewElementStates.ReadOnly).Index)
        //    DB_Btn_Click(sender, e);
        SendRow = true;
        DataTable DB_Table = new DataTable();
        DataGridView DB_GridView = new DataGridView();

        _DB.AddRow(LeadsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex], SendRow);
        if (!_DB.Visible)
        {
            _DB.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            _DB.BringToFront();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Hide();
    }
}
```

The Database Form:

```
    public DataTable DB_Table;
    BindingList<DataPile> DB_GridViewList = new BindingList<DataPile>();

    public Database()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitDBTable();
        DB_GridView.DataSource = DB_GridViewList;
    }

    public void AddRow(DataGridViewRow DB_GridViewRow, bool SendRow)
    {
        if (DB_GridViewList != null && SendRow == true)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in DB_GridView.Rows)
                if (dr.Cells[0].Value == DB_GridViewRow.Cells[0].Value)
                    return;
            DB_GridViewList.Add(new DataPile
            {
                UniqueID = (string)DB_GridViewRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue,
                BusinessName = (string)DB_GridViewRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue,
                PhoneNumber = (string)DB_GridViewRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue
            });
        }

    }

    public class DataPile
    {
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MonthlyRevenue { get; set; }
    }

    private void InitDBTable()
    {
        DB_Table = new DataTable("DB_GridTable");
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("UniqueID", typeof(string));            
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Business Name", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Phone Number", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Mobile Number", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Contact Name", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        DB_Table.Columns.Add("Monthly Revenue", typeof(string));
        DB_GridView.DataSource = DB_Table;
        // Hide UniqueID column
        //DB_GridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }

    private void Database_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        e.Cancel = true; // this cancels the close event.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Troy Mac1ure, I guess I was over thinking the original problem but, your logic was exactly what I needed to complete the copy button. +1 Cheers!